# Error attempting to import sqlite3 in a Svelte component

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, svelte

Trying to import sqlite3 in a Svelte component. I've rebuilt sqlite3 with `electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3` and have added the line `import sqlite3 from 'sqlite3'` in my script section in the main svelte file App.svelte. when I run `npm run electron` I get the error below. Svelte is new to me, I'm stumped. Thoughts appreciated.

[image]

Comment: When I get errors in conjunction with JSON parsing, I always first check if my JSON contains any comments (which it must not) and remove them. So I suggest checking your `PeanutNotes/package.json`

Comment: This is most likely due to somewhere having `key { ... }` in your package.json instead of the (correct) format of `key: { ... }`

Comment: That was it, I'd wrapped a line in curly brackets. Staring right at me.

Thanks.